# Draw a finite state machine for a welding machine

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to draw a fsm for a welding machine. So far I have the following table, which I think is right..
The system has three normal states: stopped, started, and welding. It will only transition from stopped to started when the power button is pressed, and from started to welding when the weld button is pressed, then from weld to stopped when the power button is pressed again. The system only has a single output: a signal called fail, which is set to a 1 if there is an incorrect sequence of button presses. Adding a failed state makes the system easy to implement as a Moore machine. The state transition table would look something like:

[image]

Following that description can anyone help me with the design please? It has been a long time since I did something very similar.

Comment: What about scratch starting, or RF starting, or overcurrent, overheating or duty cycle considerations? Does it need to feed welding wire? Or is this a homework question rather than a real welder? If so, say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here you are the correct FSM you asking for!

Answer (score 0):

The flip flop is used for change states over the time using a clock. If you go on wikipwdia you can easily find Flip Flop D description.

You can read this link for learning FSM:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Seq/fsm.html

First you learn sequential logic you have to know basic combinatory logic rules. If you don't I reccomend to read something about it.

You can practice using "logicly" software, search it on google. Have fun!

Comment: Hey Danny. I wanted to point out that our site format is a little different from other forums out there. If you need to make additions to an answer of yours, just edit it, instead of posting additional answers like you did. Click the "edit" button right below the answer and improve it. The system will take care of storing all the edit history for you. Then, you can delete the additional answers you posted. I suggest you do that before other users start to complain and downvote your answers.